# 306 Peugeot Vivante 1.9 diesel won't start – I have changed glow plugs and relay

Tags: starting, troubleshooting, diesel, peugeot

306 Vivante turbo diesel won't start. It has new glow plugs and relay, exhaust is leaking badly in first section and the turbo is on the way out, but turns good thought it would at least fire up.

What things should I be checking?

Comment: What do you see and hear when you try to start it?

Comment: Also does it draw enough current to be paying all the glow plugs?

Comment: I'm wondering if with the bad turbo there isn't enough compression and it's quenching itself.

Comment: @paulster2. Are you suggesting that the turbo is used during the starting of the engine?

Comment: @HandyHowie - Spit balling. I don't know, but since you said that it sounds wrong ;-)

Comment: @HandyHowie - I was actually thinking if the turbo wasn't running (spinning at all) it might be causing an obstruction in the intake, which could cause a lack of air and a very rich condition. If this were so, it would act like the engine was flooded and not want to start. Like I said, spit balling.

Comment: @ᴘᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I understand now :-)     It looks like we are talking to ourselves on this one here.

Answer (score 2):

There could be many things wrong here. I would start with the usual suspects, as follows:

- Can you verify that fuel is getting to the injectors? What is the status of the throttle plate while the car is turning over?
- Are you able to read the OBD codes set by the engine to determine failures (this might not be possible depending on the model year of the car - what is it, btw)?
- How did you know that the glow plugs needed changing and can you test whether the new ones are indeed good?
- While the car turns over, what is going on with the exhaust? Does the car belch out clouds of smoke when being turned over? Is anything visibly coming out of the tail pipe?